# Drop Down List with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a drop down list over the menu ,don't know how can i make with PHP, all the web pages or tutorials that i have seen before make it from the admin and with a template pre maked so I'm stagnant because i don't know how to make it, i'm sure that it could be something so simple i hope someone can help me, i'm using bootstrap if that helps in something

to getting the menu I'm using

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
        'container' => 'nav',
        'container_class' => 'menu-sitio'
    );
    wp_nav_menu($args);
?>
```

but in my WordPress admin menu there are something like this

[image]

and in my templete looks like

[image]

and i want to know how to make it like a drop down menu

what i just have in my HTML is this

```
<header>
    <nav class="navegacion">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    logo
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <?php 
                        $args = array(
                            'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
                            'container' => 'nav',
                            'container_class' => 'menu-sitio'
                        );
                        wp_nav_menu($args);
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you provide your current markup for your drop down list?

Comment: @cwanjt I'm sorry but I don't know what do you mean with markup, I newest in WordPress, just what I have of code is what I paste over my question

Comment: Your HTML code.

Comment: @cwanjt that's what i just have in my html, i start from 0

Comment: You need CSS to make dropdowns work if you are making custom theme. Check few links like https://perishablepress.com/css-dropdown-menu-wordpress/ http://www.xorbin.com/tutorials/wordpress-css-only-dropdown-menu-code-snippet

Comment: You may want to consider [Bootstrap Navwalker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker)

Answer (score 0):

Try below piece of code which is working for me please check and let me know is it working for you or not:

lets consider your menu is primary selected from admin section:

```
<?php
global $post;
$locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
$primaryMenuID = $locations['primary'];
$primarMenu = wp_get_nav_menu_items($primaryMenuID);
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($primarMenu as $menu) {
    if ($menu->menu_item_parent == 0) {
        $menuParsentId = $menu->ID;
        $childMenu = get_nav_menu_item_children($menuParsentId, $primarMenu);
        $menuParsenttitle = $menu->title;
        if (count($childMenu) > 0) {
            $id = get_the_ID();                                        
            ?>
            <li class="custom-dropdown
            <?php
            foreach ($child as $childobject) {
                if ($id == $childobject->object_id) {
                    echo 'active';
                }
            }
            ?>">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="drop-down-sub-menu" title="<?php echo $menuParsenttitle; ?>"><?php echo $menuParsenttitle; ?></a>
                <ul class="custom-dropdown-menu">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($child as $new) {
                        $menuChildTitle = $new->title;                            
                        ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $new->url; ?>" title="<?php echo $menuChildTitle; ?>">
                                <span class="menu-img-title"><?php echo $menuChildTitle; ?></span>
                            </a></li>

                    <?php } //} ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <?php } else {
            ?>
            <li class="<?php
            if ($id == $menu->object_id) {
                echo 'active';
            }
            ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $menu->url; ?> " title="<?php echo $menuParsenttitle; ?>"><?php echo $menuParsenttitle; ?></a></li>
            <?php
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
</ul>
```